# Get documentation from GitHub project as a single pdf

Tags: github, github-pages, erpnext, frappe

I'm looking for a single pdf of the [ErpNext](http://frappe.github.io/erpnext/user/manual/en/) and [Frappe](http://frappe.github.io/frappe/user/en/) user manuals.

Documentation seems to be provided in html and the source is in markdown. I did find tools to convert markdown to html/pdf, but no reliable solution to generate a SINGLE pdf file keeping the structure as shown here:

Put more abstractly: How to transform GitHub markdown documentation (organized in subdirectories) into a single pdf file?

Could anyone help me out? 
Any way of achieving this is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert markdown to PDF with Pandoc or similar tools.
You can fsearch the internet about how to concatenate files on your OS.
There are several (online) tools to merge multiple PDFs into one.

To create a single file you can either

- concatenate the markdown files into one big file, then convert to PDF, or
- convert all markdown files to PDF, then merge all PDF files into one big PDF.